# Optimizing MySQL query: long list of IN vs narrowing down search first

Tags: mysql, sql, select, optimization

When doing a SELECT with a big list of IN, would it be faster to narrow down the search first?

Assumptions:

- id is Primary Key
- table has 2M rows
- IDs in @list_of_id are always close together, but not sequential (selecting a subset of group of people created around the same month)

How should the following queries perform when @list_of_id is 1K long, 10K long, or 100K long?

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE id IN (@list_of_id);
```

Query 2a (Narrow down the search first):

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE id <= @max_id
    AND id >= @min_id
    AND id IN (@list_of_id);
```

Query 2b (probably slower):

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE MONTH(created) = @month
    AND id IN (@list_of_id);
```

Comment: Can you do this as a `JOIN`?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but have you tried it? What did you observe? Performance is going to be indeterminable by us without further detail: are there indices? any other keys?  What is the datatype of `id`?

Comment: If you want to know which is faster, **try them all**. You want an index on id in any case, so make sure that is done first.

Comment: If @list_of_id is sequence of numbers, you could use BETWEEN.

Comment: But a guess, I would say 2a is probably best, because it's an index range query.

Comment: The size of your query is going to be limited unless you change some default packet size settings (i.e. you might not be able to do an `IN` with 100k items without fiddling with database/server settings). For all of these, I would put your list of lookup IDs in a temporary table and do a `JOIN`. An index on `created` date might not be a bad idea either, and then combine the temporary table approach with 2b.

Comment: In most flavors of SQL that I'm familiar with, `WHERE x IN (a,b,c)` is like saying `WHERE x=a OR x=b OR x=c`. Looking at it like that can show that it can get pretty intensive with a large `IN` set. Also, if you do `MONTH(created)` you'll lose any index on `created`.

Comment: How is the list of id values getting generated to begin with?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I'm currently lacking the tools to test this at present location. Therefore I posted here as a hypothetical question hoping someone who has the experience can answer. But will definitely try it out next week when I'm in front of my dev computer. Good point on size limitation on list_of_id. Will probably put this in a temporary table.

Comment: @Uueerdo A subquery or a temporary table. The main thing I'm curious about is if doing id BETWEEN min_id AND max_id before the IN will help speed up the query.

Comment: If it is already in temp table, you are better off indexing that temp table and then joining to it.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL 5.6 introduced some optimizer improvements specifically for long lists of ids in an `IN()` predicate.  Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html#equality-range-optimization

That optimization is relevant if you are relying on an index for the `IN()` search. If you narrow down the search first as in your query 2a, the index will be used for the inequality expression, but not for the `IN()` predicate.

In general, when you have multiple search terms, only one range predicate will be optimized with an index. A range predicate is anything other than `=`.

So in your 2a example, the `BETWEEN` predicate will use the index (I believe the pair of inequality expressions you used will be optimized as if it is one `BETWEEN` predicate), and then the `IN()` predicate will just search linearly through the result of the first index scan.

In your 2b example, trying to narrow down the search with `MONTH(created)` cannot use an index at all. Think of looking up people in a phone book—if I ask you to find everyone whose *middle* initial is "J." then the fact that the phone book is sorted by last name doesn't help you.

You might like to view my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: Thank you @bill-karwin! This is a really good insight. Watching the video now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Query 1.

A simple `IN(long-list)` will leapfrog through the index (`PRIMARY KEY` in your case).  This will be more efficient than any of your alternatives.

You can 'prove' this by doing

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

When I tried it with 146 items in the `IN`, I got

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 0     |
| Handler_read_key           | 146   |  <-- note
... (other things with "0")
```

This says that it actually probed the index only 146 times.

I've seen 70K items in an IN list.  The query took some time, but it did not die and was even reasonably fast, considering that the resultset had 70K rows.

(Caveat:  I tested 5.6.22; some older versions (5.1?) may have operated less efficiently.)

If your list of ids is already in another table, then `JOIN` to that table.  That will be faster than pulling out the ids out of the server and sending them back into the server.